Does EFCore Where( ... set.Contains(...)) care whether Set is List or HashSet?
Suppose I an using EFCore to query a SQL DB, and I write:
myTableDbSet.Where(entity => filterSet.Contains(entity.Id))
Then does it make any difference (e.g. to performance) what the concrete type of filterSet is?
In general C# it would matter ... aLargeHashSet.Contains(val) is much faster than aLargeList.Contains(val). But does it make any difference in EF?
I would guess not? I would guess that it's going to iterate over the collection to write a string of values into an IN() clause.
But that's just guessing. Does anyone have an informed opinion?

EF is transforming the c# query to an sql query and sends this sql query to the sql server. so even if you implement a different collection with different logic the transformed query contains all elements of the collection as you said will it transform to a query like 'IN(...)'

Then does it make any difference (e.g. to performance) what the concrete type of filterSet is?
No, it does not (at least in a significant way), since EF Core translates the LINQ query to an SQL one. See the How Queries Work docs:

These parts of the query are translated to database-specific query language (for example, SQL for a relational database)

And if EF Core does not translate this particular part of LINQ query then perfromance-wise it would be much more beneficial to fix that rather than selecting more appropriate collection.
